# Nested list or list of string pairs

Tags: python, nested-loops, nested-lists

I have some pairs of strings. First contains name, second contains city of birth.
I use them in web scraping. When I find appropriate element on web page I want in for loop make send_keys(name) and do other operations like click or enter. For second element from web page I want also make for loop and send_keys(city). How can I do it?
Should I make list of string pairs or nested list?

Like:

`list_1 = [["Ann", "London"], ["John", "Barcelona"], ["Kate", "Paris"]]`

`list_2 = [("Ann", "London"), ("John", "Barcelona"), ("Kate", "Paris")]`

What is better if my double iteration should look like:

```py
for element in list_1:
   el_scraped = driver.find.....
   el_scraped.send_keys(element)
   el_scraped.click()
   for element2 in element:
   el2_scraped = driver.find ....
   el2_scarped.send_keys(element2)
   el2_scraped.click()
```

I have a problem with for loop construction. I only post some operations between one loop and another. Can someone help me with for loops and make appropriate list?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the data in any iterator unless you call them appropriately.
I don't see any necessity for a nested `for` loop.
For the data format in `list_1` you can call them as below:

```
for name,city in list_1:
    el_scraped = driver.find.....
    el_scraped.send_keys(name)
    el_scraped.click()
    el2_scraped = driver.find ....
    el2_scarped.send_keys(city)
    el2_scraped.click()
```

Comment: Your `list_1` is a list of list. Whenever we iterate a nested list, each element will be another list. so in your case the first element is the "name" and the second element is the "city"